# Warning: Attempt to present vc whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3

So I'm attempting to a cue a segue from a model VC to run on the root VC however when I attempt to do so it gives me this error - Warning: Attempt to present vc whose view is not in the window hierarchy. I tried the viewWIllAppear() but that also doesn't work because my VC only covers half the root vc's view as it is a side menu. However, after cueing a segue directly from the root VC it works fine.

this is the code that I have rn:

```
dismiss(animated: true) {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController
    vc?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToSubmition", sender: self)

}
```

Comment: Your main VC is embedded to the UINavigationController?

Comment: You might be calling it from the viewdidload method if so it'll give this warning

Comment: @Mannopson yah in storyboard its set to model with that code to my NavigationController

Comment: Post the notification to your MainVC whenever dismiss action is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. you couldn't call another view controller by creating an instance. instead I just called the present VC at the time

```
dismiss(animated: true) {
        if let mainView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MainViewController {
            mainView.ToSubmition()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dismissing the view controller first:

```
dismiss(animated: true) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true) { 
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToSubmition", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code that I have, it is similar to yours but it still gives the same error

Comment: Did you create the manual segue in your storyboard?  I'm not sure why you trying to instantiate a new view controller, it should already be in your hierarchy.

Comment: I modified my answer.  Try replacing your code completely with mine.  You should not be instantiating another view controller.  As long as the manual segue was created correctly in your storyboard, and the parent view controller is next in the hierarchy, my code should work for you.

Comment: but adding the performSegue on the side menu view controller after being dismissed wouldn't run. I get this error when I run that code - (<Happening.SideMenuViewController: 0x7fa3d07485f0>) has no segue with identifier 'ToSubmition'. However when I add a segue from the side menu VC to the other VC it says that the side menu VC is no longer in the view hierarchy

Comment: Did you try my code?  I am doing the exact same thing on my app.  I have a split view controller and I am dismissing it from the left side and going back to the previous VC with this code exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to present a VC from your side menu, which of course can't be done as the view is not in the window's hierarchy. What you can do is to make use of NSNotificationCenter to post a notification key once the function is called and dismiss your side menu. Then in your Main VC, add an observer and create a function to perform your intended segue.

You can read from the [Apple API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) on how to implement NSNotification Center.

Answer (score 0):

- Completion handlers always uses the `background thread`, to do UI updates or something like yours use `main thread`

  ```
  dismiss(animated: true) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController
      vc?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToSubmition", sender: self)
    }
  }
  ```
- If it fails use `dispatch_after` and set some delay before performing `segue`.

  ```
  dismiss(animated: true) {
    let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5)
    mainQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
       // ...perform segue
    }
  }
  ```
- It is a blind shot give it a try.